# Call function inside __construct with php

Tags: php, construct

A simple PHP problem I couldn't find the answer to.

Is it possible to call a function from the "__construct()"?

For example if I use the My_Controller solution [here](http://davidwinter.me/articles/2009/02/21/authentication-with-codeigniter/). If I add my own function below, like if I have a more advanced auth, can I call it from the construct?

Comment: Have you tried it? Of course you can call functions inside methods.

Comment: oh my god..... that was the most embarrassing brainfreeze moment in a very long time. Tried it and ofc it worked like a charm.. :) Thanks

Comment: No worries, such things happen :) But it is always better to try things first ;)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, using the format `$this->myNewFunction();`

Comment: how on earth did this get to be -1??! +1 because it's right!