# use function __construct() for static functions?

Tags: php, class, construct

I wanna to use this way but i have a problem , `function __construct()` dosn't work ? Why ?

```
class user{

  function __construct(){
    define('HI', 'hello');
  }

  static function say_hi(){

     echo HI ;
  }
}

user::say_hi();// Out put should be : hello
```

Comment: `$test = new user();`

Comment: i need to use static function .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call function inside \_\_construct with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533724/call-function-inside-construct-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new instance of class `user` inside `say_hi()` method. When you create the instance inside `say_hi()` method, it will call the constructor method and subsequently define the constant `HI`.

So your code should be like this:

```
class user{
    function __construct(){
        define('HI', 'hello');
    }

    static function say_hi(){
        new user();
        echo HI ;
    }
}

user::say_hi();
```

Output:

```
hello
```

Comment: Thanks   for solotion     :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way only if you have **PHP version >= 7**

```
class User{

  function __construct(){
    define('HI', 'hello');
  }

  static function say_hi(){

     echo HI ;
  }
}

(new User())::say_hi();
```

Comment: No i don't use . What's the similar way when use a static function ?

Comment: Then define it globally within class or outside of the class something like as `const HI = 'hello';` or simply call the class within static function

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is only called when initializing a class for example `$user = new user();`. When calling a static function a class isn't initialized thus the constructor is not called.

Comment: Whats's the solotion ?i need this way !